# How do I find a certain brush?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

In Adobe Photoshop I always use the default brush, but then I clicked something by accident and now it has changed with no easy way to change back. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If what you're asking is how to get back to the default set of brushes, click on the arrow next to the brush thumbnail in the control panel, click on the gear icon, and select "Reset Brushes..."

[image]